# AWS Get API Gateway URL for Use in Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I'm looking to use CloudFormation to build my AWS stack which includes an API Gateway with Usage Plans. I'd like to specify my usage plans in my main CloudFormation template, rather than having to add them as a change-set after the initial stack create. The problem is that the stack fails to create when I include the usage plan because (I think) the API Gateway is not finished deploying when it tries to create the usage plans since I get an error saying that the stage "prod" does not exist. My CloudFormation template (extract) looks like this:

```
  Api:
    Properties:
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      DefinitionUri: {MYS3URL}
      StageName: prod
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  ApiFreeUsagePlan:
    DependsOn: Api
    Properties:
      ApiStages:
      - ApiId:
          Ref: Api
        Stage: prod
      Description: Free usage plan
      UsagePlanName: Free
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
```

I thought adding `DependsOn: Api` to the usage plan definition would work but it doesn't so I'm out of ideas?

It seems like my DependsOn statement should be on the ApiDeployment which I can see in the stack create events is still in progress when it tries to create the usage plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found that can do this is by setting the DependsOn property of the Usage plan to the logical Api Stage name which is {LogicalApiName}{StageName}Stage for example in my case:

```
Api:
  Properties:
    CacheClusterEnabled: true
    CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
    DefinitionUri: {MYS3URL}
    StageName: prod
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
ApiFreeUsagePlan:
  DependsOn: ApiprodStage
```

I don't like this as it relies on the logical stage naming convention which I don't believe is officially documented in the AWS CloudFromation docs, however it appears to be the only reliable option